# header li + li separator placement trouble

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to get a separator between my nav menu and I found out about the 'li + li' function, but I'm having a very hard time getting the separator in the right place. I'm trying to get it evenly place between the two placeholders centered and all. I've tried messing with the margin and padding properties with no luck.

Here's a jsfiddle along with my code and a picture example on what I'm trying to achieve. Any help is much appreciated, thanks.

[image]

http://jsfiddle.net/jzcZ4/

**HTML / CSS**

```
<style>

body {
    margin: 0;
    color:white;;
}

#header {
    background-color: #1c2024;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 100px;
}

#header ul {
    margin: 0;
}

#header li {
    display:inline;
}

#header li + li {
    background:url('http://i.imgur.com/IdVT0cL.png') no-repeat;
    padding-left: 20px;
    padding-right: 20px;
}

</style>

</head>

<body>
    <div id="wrapper">
        <div id="header">
            <ul>
                <li>odsfjkoj</li>
                <li>odsfjkoj</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Why don't you just use border with defined color? Image in this case is useless. You can use border-right: 1px solid #666; and li:last-child border: none; rules.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would use [**`background-size`/`background-position`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background) in order to position the background.

In this instance, just use the shorthand:

[**UPDATED EXAMPLE HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/9k2gE/)

```
#header li + li {
    background: url('http://i.imgur.com/IdVT0cL.png') 8px 8px / 1px 10px no-repeat;
    padding-left: 20px;
}
```

Comment: I never knew there was a such thing as position / size for the background property. Good to learn something new every day. Works perfectly, though I had to tweak the position to my fitting. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 0):

I would make the `li` elements `display:block` and apply padding to all of the on left and right.. This way they have equal distances from both sides of the text

Then use `50%` on the vertical position of the background image.

```
#header li {
    display:inline-block;
    padding: 0 20px;
}

#header li + li {
    background:url('http://i.imgur.com/IdVT0cL.png') 0 50% no-repeat;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/jzcZ4/1/

(*I have used a trick of commenting out the whitespace so that it does not affect the layout..*)